# Can HTML5's download attribute be used to trigger native file handler on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, ios11

I have a page that displays a gallery of images, and each image has a download link which forces the file to be downloaded rather than opening it in the browser.

Sample code: 
`<a href="file.gif" download="some-file-name.gif">Download</a>`

This works perfectly in Chrome desktop, but I'd like it to work for mobile as well.

Is there any way to trigger the native file handler for iOS/Android?

**Note:** this is all front-end, so any answer which may involve modifying the `.htaccess` file won't work for me.

Comment: Works on Android for me. https://jsfiddle.net/shtfxj3h/

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks for testing. Sadly, I only have an iPhone at my disposal and it doesn't seem to work; it just loads the content in the browser.

Comment: ... Yes, IIRC ios Safari doesn't allow this, and it's probable that ios Chrome suffers from this limitation too. ios file system is a thing anyway, not sure what could be done from those saved files (but it's been a long I didn't used it, so my judgement might be wrong)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised at all to find out that iOS doesn't allow this tpe of thing, but I figured since they added the file system controls with iOS 11 (maybe?) this would be doable.

Comment: As I said it's been a long time, and I don't even know what is *file system controls* but fast reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) I understand apps still only have access to  a sandboxed filesystem i.e would actually be the same thing as saving in IndexedDB.